# How to move protein coordinates with respect to a reference frame

Tags: python, biopython, protein-database

I have a PDB file '1abz' (https://files.rcsb.org/view/1ABZ.pdb), which is containing the coordinates of a protein structure. Please ignore the lines of the header remarks, the interesting information starts at line 276 which says 'MODEL 1'.

I would like to shift the coordinates with respect to a reference frame at the origin (i.e x=0, y=0, z=0) and generate a new coordinate file.

I read through biopython tutorial (http://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ), used the transform method of the Atom object (http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.Atom.Atom-class.html#transform), and came up with this script but no success.

How can I go about this? Many thanks in advance!

```
from Bio import PDB
import numpy as np

parser = PDB.PDBParser()
io = PDB.PDBIO()
struct = parser.get_structure('1abz','1abz.pdb')

for model in struct:
    for chain in model:
        for residue in chain:
            for atom in residue:
                def rotmat():
                    rotation = rotmat(np.pi, Vector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
                    translation = np.array((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 'f')
                    atom.transform(rotation, translation)

io.set_structure(struct)
io.save('1abz_coord.pdb')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your last loop `for atom in residue` you are defining the function `rotmat` every time you loop over an atom but you never call the function.
- Try removing the line `def rotmat():`
- Currently both your `rotation` and your `translation` wouldn't change the atom coordinates.

If you want for example to define `C1` as your reference point you could use the following code.

`rotation_matrix` is just a matrix which does not rotate your protein. `np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])` would do the same.

```
from Bio import PDB
import numpy as np

parser = PDB.PDBParser()
io = PDB.PDBIO()
struct = parser.get_structure('1abz','1abz.pdb')

rotation_matrix = PDB.rotmat(PDB.Vector([0, 0, 0]), PDB.Vector([0, 0, 0]))

for atom in struct.get_atoms():
    atom_C1 = atom.coord.copy()
    break

for model in struct:
    for chain in model:
        for residue in chain:
            for atom in residue:
                atom.transform(rotation_matrix, -atom_C1)

io.set_structure(struct)
io.save('1abz_coord.pdb')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 

Also, how can I get only x coordinates for example.
I set the transformed coordinates to a variable 'coord' (i.e coord = atom.transform(rotation_matrix, -atom_C1). Then I set x = coord[30:38] but I got an error message.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question but you `atom.coord` is a numpy array.  `atom.coord[0]` would give you the x-value, 1 --> y, 2 --> z.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried your method `atom.coord[0]` but the coordinates are printed vertically, three times and line by line. For example:
0.807000213623
0.807000213623
0.807000213623
2.84700017548
2.84700017548
2.84700017548
1.16100030518
1.16100030518
1.16100030518
3.08599954224
3.08599954224
3.08599954224
1.40100007629
1.40100007629
1.40100007629

Comment: Hm, that's strange:
`for model in struct:
    for chain in model:
        for residue in chain:
            for atom in residue:
                print(atom.coord[0])` gives me a new line separated list of single x-coordinates